# Slider with fixed height and variable width images

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, slider

I'm trying to create a slider with fixed height and variable width images. I need the slider to be 100% width of the page, and be responsive to the browser viewport.

I would prefer not to use JS.

**HTML**

```
<div id="photoframeContainer">
  <div id="photoframe">
    <div class="imageContainer"><img id="theImage" src="uploads/picture02.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="imageContainer"><img id="theImage" src="uploads/picture03.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="imageContainer"><img id="theImage" src="uploads/picture04.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="imageContainer"><img id="theImage" src="uploads/picture05.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="imageContainer"><img id="theImage" src="uploads/picture06.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="imageContainer"><img id="theImage" src="uploads/picture07.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="imageContainer"><img id="theImage" src="uploads/picture08.jpg" alt=""></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Fiddle of failed previous attempt**

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DLEG9/)

This is a fiddle of a previous attempt to achieve what I want, however the page isn't responsive as when the browser is resized, the images overlap and behave not as intended.

Comment: provide fiddle will be better?

Comment: Is this what you need? http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/8Q273/

Comment: Wow that is spot on! Thank you @web-tiki! Would you like to write it up as an answer so i could properly credit your reply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your layout by simplifying the HTML (BTW ids must be unique so you shouldn't use the sane id on all the images) :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/8Q273/)**

```
<div id="photoframe">
    <img class="test" src="" alt="" />
    <img class="test" src="" alt="" />
    ...
</div>
```

*CSS :*

```
body, html {
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
}

#photoframe {
    white-space:nowrap;
    height:50%;
}
img {
    height:100%;
    width:auto;
}
```